# Create entry for nested model with has_many and through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models with simple associations.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :blogs
end

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
   # Blog has 'title' column
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :entries
end

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base 
   # Entry has 'article' column 
   belongs_to :blog
end
```

I'm making an JSON API to create new Entry. One special requirement is to create Blog if not exists. The JSON input should be like

```
 { "entry" : 
           { "article" : "my first blog entry", 
             "blog" : 
                    { "title": "My new blog" }
           }
 }
```

If the blog exists add the entry to the blog. I'm implementing 'entries#create' method and what I want to do is something like

```
 def create
     @user = Users.find(params[:user_id]) # :user_id is given in URL
     # I want to do something like
     # @user.entries.create(params[:entry])
     #     or
     # @user.create(params[:entry])
     # but this doesn't work.
 end
```

What I want to ask here is if I have to manually parse the JSON first and create blog object and then create entry object. If possible I want to make the models accept such input and works correctly.

Another possible solution is to change the API and make it in blogs controller and accept JSON like

```
  { "blog" : 
           { "title" : "My new blog", 
             "article_attributes" :
                    { "article": "my first blog entry" }
           }
  }
```

but because of some reasons, I can't make the API like this. (The JSON's first node must be "entry" not "blog")

What I have tried so far is to add "accepts_nested_attributes_for" in the Entry model.

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base 
   # Entry has 'article' column 
   belongs_to :blog
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :blog
end
```

and then post JSON like

```
 { "entry" : 
           { "article" : "my first blog entry", 
             "blog_attributes" : 
                    { "title": "My new blog" }
           }
 }
```

then in the controller

```
 @user.entries.create(params[:entry])
```

It seems that Rails tries to create "blog" entry with this code but fails because the "blog_attributes" doesn't include 'user_id'. I can add user_id to the params in my controller but it looks awkward since I'm writing `@user.entries.create` which should tell which user I'm working on now.

Is there any good way to make it all work as I wanted? (or am I doing something totally wrong?)

Comment: The `accepts_nested_attributes_for` functionality works the other way. You can have Blog accept nested attributes for Entries, since the relation works that way. Having the Entry accept attributes for it's parent (the Blog) seems a bit backward, no?

Comment: Yes, what I'm doing is opposite of usual object creation. But that is what I want to do now. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is just my trial and I'm not sure if it works. I want to know if there is some good practice or patterns for this.

Comment: I think you need to create the Blog before adding entries to it, so I don't think `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is your friend here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Ok remove the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :blog` from your entry model

And in your blog model put `accepts_nested_attributes_for :entries, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true`

**In your JSON do this:**

```
{ "blog" : 
           { "title" : "My new blog", 
             "entry" : 
                    { "article": "my first blog entry" }
           }
 }
```

**In your blogs_controller.rb do this:**

```
def blog_params
  params.require(:blog).permit(:id, :title, entries_attributes: [:id, :article, :_destroy])
end
```

**and in your blogs_controller.rb new action:**

```
def new 
 @blog = Blog.new
 @blog.entries.build
end
```

**// in your blogs_controller create action:**

```
def create
  @user = Users.find(params[:user_id]) # :user_id is given in URL
  @user.blog.create(blog_params)
end
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, it cannot be accepted to use JSON whose first node is 'blog'.